# IIS changing enable32BitAppOnWin64 option on one pool affects all pools

Tags: iis

If I change the enable32BitAppOnWin64 option on one pool all other pools will change their enable32BitAppOnWin64 option to the same value as the changed one.

I guess this behavior isn't by design. What could be wrong with my IIS ?

Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

```
<applicationPools>
            <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
            <add name="Classic .NET AppPool" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
            <add name="ASP.NET v4.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
            <add name="ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
            <add name="SharePoint Web Services Root" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="LocalService" idleTimeout="00:00:00" pingingEnabled="true" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
            </add>
            <add name="SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="LocalSystem" idleTimeout="00:00:00" pingingEnabled="true" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
            </add>
            <add name="0d0efe5a69aa4e14b9e9f593b3bb2551" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="NetworkService" idleTimeout="00:00:00" pingingEnabled="true" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
            </add>
            <add name="SharePoint Central Administration v4" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="NetworkService" loadUserProfile="true" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                            <add value="02:43:00" />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
                <failure rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes="10" />
            </add>
            <add name="SharePoint - 80" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="NetworkService" loadUserProfile="true" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                            <add value="01:26:00" />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
                <failure rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes="10" />
            </add>
            <add name="9da36b17dcf54ae08e904d43467e6c0b" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="NetworkService" idleTimeout="00:00:00" pingingEnabled="true" />
                <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                    <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                        <schedule>
                            <clear />
                        </schedule>
                    </periodicRestart>
                </recycling>
            </add>
            <add name="Icp" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults enable32BitAppOnWin64="true">
                <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Application Pool Defaults` has the `enable32BitAppOnWin64` option set to `false`.

Comment: Didn't help. If I set one pool to true, all pools have true and vica verse.

Comment: If the option is explicitly set to `false` in the Application Pool Defaults configuration, it will not change for all, just because you change it for one. Try to copy and paste in the "Application Pools"-section from your applicationHost.config file

Comment: Ok I added the applicationPools section.

Comment: I did set enable32BitAppOnWin64 option to false in Application Pool Defaults. Then I did set enable32BitAppOnWin64 to true on the ASP.NET v 4.0 pool. Then checked back on enable32BitAppOnWin64 on Application Pool Defaults and it was true. This is weird :-)